# Can't use `dart pub get`. The command force me to use `flutter pub get`

Tags: dart-server

2 months ago I used `dart pub get` for my dart_server project on my server(Ubuntu).
After I edited my code and tried to use this command I got

```
Resolving dependencies... (1.3s)
Because dart_server depends on printing >=1.3.5 which requires the Flutter SDK, version solving
  failed.

Flutter users should run `flutter pub get` instead of `dart pub get`.
```

(I tried to use old dart_server project and I got the same error)

What happened? Once, I can use this with my project(old dart_server), but I can't use this command with the same project(old dart_server).

How to make it work?
(I only installed the dart not flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think
These api packages were updated and mush using the flutter.
So, I installed the flutter and it worked fine.